# String replacement in string

Tags: java, string, flags

Good day. So I want to ask you how to change substring in a string that I got from JEditorPane.

Im making a program for chords changin according to this: C to C# , C# to D, D# to E , E to F, F to F# , F# to G , G to G#,...

I wrote code,but it allways goes from begginging till the end.For example, if I write in JEditorPane:

"  C   D#   E " it all goes to F#. How can I just make changes for 1 step( just C to C# , D# to E , E to F)?

```
if (event.getSource()== ok)
{
    Object contents = akordib.getSelectedItem();
    if (contents == "+1 step")
    {
        finalStr = textPanel.getText();
        if (finalStr.contains(" C ") == true)
        {
            finalStr = finalStr.replaceAll(" C" , " C#");
            textPanel.setText(finalStr);
        }

        if (finalStr.contains(" C# ") == true)
        {
            finalStr = finalStr.replaceAll(" C# ", " D ");
            textPanel.setText(finalStr);
        }
    }   
}
```

Here is an example :
Original:

> C   D#   E

After the code should be:

> C# E  F

Comment: `final` is a keyword and should NOT be used as a variable name.

Comment: it is just for here,it is called konacno in my code.

Comment: You should be careful when you alter code "just here" because people might see: That code doesn't even compile and just skip this question...

Comment: I agree with @WarrenFaith on both comments.  final shouldn't be used for a variable name.  And secondly, as he stated in another comment, changing these from separate if statements to and if-else chain would probably be your easiest solution.

Answer (score 2):

Write it the other way round. It is happening, because you have already set C to C# when C# is tested.

Comment: or "if else chaining"

Comment: Yeah,but it should go all the way around. So the whole thing goes like this: CtoC#,C#toD,DtoD#,D#toE,EtoF,FtoF#,F#toG,GtoG#,G#toA,AtoA#,A#toH and HtoC.

Answer (score 1):

Your current problem is the order in which you are replacing the entries. When you start with

```
C D# E
```

and replace every C to C#, your variable will contain

```
C# D# E
```

If you then replace all the C# to D, your variable will contain

```
D D# E
```

etc.

Replacing them in the other direction would solve it, e.g. first replacing C# to D and only afterwards replacing C to C#.

The only tricky part is that you need to able to go around and replace H to C. The solution for that is to start with replacing H with X (or any other character which does not occur), do all the other substitutions in the correct order and as last step replace X by C again.

Comment: just one question,so, i should put it like this:
replaceAll("C#","D").replaceAll(" C " , " C# ")

but how to continuo so I dont have colission like I had before?

Answer (score 0):

First off, you probably shouldn't be using `final` as the name of a variable as `final` is a keyword in Java.

Second, you should probably split the string on a space and then cycle through that array bumping each note a half step.

```
String notes = textPanel.getText();
String[] notesArr = notes.split(" ");
StringBuilder newNotes = new StringBuilder();
for(int i=0; i < notesArr.length; i++) {
    String newNote = moveHalfStep(notesArr[i]);
    newNotes.append(newNote);
    newNotes.append(" ");
}
textPanel.setText(newNotes.toString());

private String moveHalfStep(String note) {
    String newNote = "";
    if(note.contains("#")) {
        char[] noteChars = note.toCharArray();
        char noteChar = noteChars[0];
        noteChar++;
        if(noteChar == 'H') {
            noteChar = 'A';
        }
        newNote = String.valueOf(noteChar);
    } else {
        newNote = note + "#";
    }

    return String.valueOf(newNote);
}
```